# How to setup maven for two different projects with different profile

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a Maven project setup successfully and executing as per requirement using eclipse.

Now I want to setup and execute another maven project with different profile from a different IDE(IntelliJ).

but as soon as I had added second project i started getting conflicts and errors in second project's pom.And I am not able to setup the second project.I tried multiple solutions and tricks, even deleted .m2 folder and then rebuilt the project but nothing works.

All these solutions only impacted 1st project (which I setup and built again and it is now working fine).

What should I do to get both projects work simultaneously?

**Errors getting while trying to setup second project:**

Failure to find com.WOW:parent:pom:2.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

- Note:

  There is no problem with WOW, it is present on remote location.Same project has been successfully setup on another machine where it is the only project and no other maven project is present there.

Comment: Is the name of the project the same? Can you post the `pom.xml`s? Can you post the errors?

Comment: No both projects have different names. I am going to edit the post and share the errors there.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.m2` directory and building the problematic project via the command line **without building the first project nor starting any of your IDEs**?

Comment: can you share the pom..xml too.

Comment: Have you tried importing the project into eclipse? What happens?

Comment: first project (in eclipse) is working fine, It is the second project that is not working.

Comment: I mean importing the second project into Eclipse

Comment: @dan1st It is the requirement to use second project with different IDE.

Comment: Just to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The normal layout for a maven multi module project is:

```
parent
├── pom.xml
├── module
    ├── pom.xml
```

Check that you use this layout.

Additionally:

the relativePath looks strange. Instead of '..'

```
<relativePath>..</relativePath>
```

try '../' instead:

```
<relativePath>../</relativePath>
```

You can also remove relativePath if you use the standard layout. This is what I always do, and on the command line I can build as well the parent (and all modules) or only a single module.

The module path may be wrong. In the parent you define the module as:

```
<module>junitcategorizer.cutdetection</module>
```

You must specify the name of the folder of the child module, not an artifact identifier. If junitcategorizer.cutdetection is not the name of the folder than change it accordingly.

Hope that helps..